# Maintenance Job not running but not Failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, maintenance-plans

I set up a maintenance plan that contains three sub-plans.  One sub-plan for hourly log backups, one sub-plan for daily maintenance, one for weekly maintenance.  These are custom plans set up using Ola Hallengren's [SQL Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/). 

The last sub-plan to successfully run was the hourly at 8 pm on the July 21st.  After that nothing.  No plan executions or failed executions.
I have reset the schedules and still, the plan does not run.  When I manually execute each sub-plan they complete successfully.  The maintenance plan history does not say anything, as if the plan is just not running. 


I am stumped as to what could be causing the failure of the scheduled job.

I ran a simple test job, executing `Select 1` every minute for 4 minutes, and the schedule worked.

**Discovered that the schedules had been disabled. I have re-enabled them and the maintenance plan is running as expected. #PEBKAC ;)**

[image: Daily Maintenance Plan Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the Maintenance Plans feature, simply create a SQL Server Agent Job with steps for each of the tasks you've defined in the plan.

SQL Server Agent Jobs provide a far easier mechanism to control flow of jobs, and provides great success/failure alerting.

Check that the schedule for the Maintenance Plan is enabled, and set to run when you expect it to...

[image]